# RaspberryPiにてGPSモジュールでエラー

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps

GPSモジュールをRaspberryPizeroに接続して、座標値を取得しようと思っているのですが、

以下ページ内の設定は終えております。
[Raspberry Piに「みちびき」対応GPSモジュールを接続](http://denor.daa.jp/raspberry-pi%E3%81%AB%E3%80%8C%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A1%E3%81%B3%E3%81%8D%E3%80%8D%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9Cgps%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A)

そして、以下ページのプログラムを作動させようとすると、
[Raspberry Pi3のPythonでGPSを扱う](https://qiita.com/AmbientData/items/fff54c8ac8ec95aeeee6)

エラーは以下です。色々な方法を試したのですが、`chmod 666`を試した際に数回だけ動作したことがあります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyS0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "gps.py", line 12, in rungps
    s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 236, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/ttyS0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyS0'
```

Comment: 「chmod 666を試した際」と質問にありますが、どのファイルのパーンミッションを変更したのでしょうか？

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます    /dev/ttyS0です

Comment: /dev/ttyS0は、端末の最初のもの(0番)を意味していて、USB接続されたシリアル通信端末(GPSデバイスにつながっている）の事だと思われます。　質問のエラーメッセージは「 '/dev/ttyS0'　がビジー状態（使用中）」というものなので、既に'/dev/ttyS0'をOpenしているのに、再度'/dev/ttyS0'をオープンした等で起きたものだと思われます。